# Floating action button captures clicks outside its bounds

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I'm trying to use the floating action button widget from the Android support library. The button shows up properly, however, it captures clicks that are not within the button itself. It accepts clicks at least a full radius outside the visible button. I don't know if it's due to the shadow, but I can click even well beyond the visible shadow and the button captures the click. Also, if I set the margins of the button to zero, there is still a large gap between the button and the edges of the screen. I have also tried to set the padding to zero, but it has no effect.

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using version `22.2.0` or `22.2.1` of the Design Library?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with 22.2.1? That was a huge bug fix release.

Comment: I just upgraded to 22.2.1 and the issue still exists.